# ListView Programatic Scroll in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I need to scroll ListView in a programmatical way. Actually, I have done partially but it works speedily and it is different from normal behaviour. How can I implement like listview normal vertical scrolling behaviour? I need just vertical scrolling. In my code, _scrollViewer is ScrollViewer of the ListView and drawingPanel is a Canvas component where upon the ListView. (Canvas should be top on the ListView, this is a reqirement.)

By the way my UI side like that :

```
<grid>
   <listview>
   </listview>
   <canvas>
   </canvas>
</grid>
```

Code Side like That :

```
PointerPoint startPoint;      
        bool pressed = false;
        private void drawingPanel_PointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pressed = true;
            startPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.drawingPanel);         
        }
        private void drawingPanel_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {         
            PointerPoint endPoint = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.drawingPanel);
            PanListViewToNewPosition(startPoint, endPoint);
        }
        private void drawingPanel_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            pressed = false;           
            startPoint = null;
        }
        private void PanListViewToNewPosition(PointerPoint start, PointerPoint end)
    {
        if (pressed)
        {               
            double verticalOffset = start.Position.Y - end.Position.Y;              
            verticalOffset += this._scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
            this._scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, verticalOffset, null);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need programmatic scrolling?

It seems that all you need is to make the `Canvas` element invisible to the pointer (touch, mouse, etc.), but still visible to the user.

It is done very simply. Set the `IsHitTestVisible` property on `Canvas` to `False`:

```
<Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False">
...
</Canvas>
```

If done this way, the `Canvas` will be on top of the `ListView`, but won't scroll - it will be static. The `ListView` will scroll. If you want the `Canvas` to scroll with the `ListView`'s content, put both elements on a `ScrollViewer`:

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <Grid>
      <ListView>
      </ListView>
      <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="False">
      </Canvas>
   </Grid>
<ScrollViewer>
```